# Discord JDA EmbedMessage Profile Link

Tags: java, bots, discord, discord-jda

Currently I'm making a rather simple logging bot for Discord. All it does is send an `EmbedMessage` to any #log channel in the server.

This little bit of messy code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {

    Message message = e.getMessage();
    User author = e.getAuthor();
    MessageChannel channel = e.getChannel();

    if (channel.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("log") && !author.isBot()) {
        message.delete().queue();
    } else {

        EmbedBuilder eBuilder = new EmbedBuilder();

        String aMention = "@" + author.getName() + "#" + author.getDiscriminator();

        eBuilder.setAuthor(aMention, null, author.getEffectiveAvatarUrl());
        eBuilder.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        eBuilder.setFooter("#" + channel.getName(), null);
        eBuilder.appendDescription(message.getContentDisplay());

        MessageEmbed embed = eBuilder.build();

        for (MessageChannel mc : e.getGuild().getTextChannels()) {
            if (mc.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("log") && !author.isBot()) {
                mc.sendMessage(embed).queue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is the setup for logging non-bot chatting. Currently, it doesn't seem to setup a direct profile link to the user talking, in the line `String aMention = "@" + author.getName() + "#" + author.getDiscriminator();`. I tried searching for a specific method that gets a profile link, but currently I am not able to find it.

Comment: You can't I think, but for get the user as mention you can just do `author.getAsMention()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mention a member, just use:

```
Member yourMember = e.getMember();

String mention = yourMember.getAsMention();

// ...your code
```